# Sort Double Double HashMap Java/Processing

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, processing

I have this Hashmap of floats and I want to get the top 5 largest values from it:

```
import java.util.Map;


HashMap<Float,Float> hm = new HashMap<Float,Float>();

// Putting key-value pairs in the HashMap
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  float pos = random(-50, 50);
  float time = random(0, 50);
hm.put(time, pos);

}
// Using an enhanced loop to interate over each entry
for (Map.Entry me : hm.entrySet()) {
  print("key is " + me.getKey());
  println(" value is " + me.getValue());
}
```

I assume I would need to sort it first. Question is, how to sort it and will the keys still remain the same after the sort? When I say "same" I mean will the sorted values still have the original key identifier? This is crucial for what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: And you've googled for `sort map by value`, right?

Comment: Instead of setting keys/values you can set values/key into a TreeMap.

Comment: Yes, all keys will point to related values.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Why and how would that be a good idea?

Comment: @solvator Thanks. This is my first time using a data structure like this so I didnt know what to expect.

Comment: Instead of it, use TreeMap. Also you can use it through SortedMap() interface using comparator.

Comment: A TreeMap is sorted by key and if you put them the other way around the values will be sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does what you do. I developed and tested it in Processing IDE.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

class FloatEntryComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry> {
  public int compare(Map.Entry e1, Map.Entry e2) {
    return ((Float)e2.getValue()).intValue() - ((Float)e1.getValue()).intValue();
  }
}

void setup() {
  Map<Float,Float> hm = new HashMap<Float,Float>();

  // Putting key-value pairs in the HashMap
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    float pos = random(-50, 50);
    float time = random(0, 50);
    hm.put(time, pos);
  }

  println("ALL ENTRIES, UNSORTED:");  
  for (Map.Entry me : hm.entrySet()) {
    print("key is " + me.getKey());
    println(" value is " + me.getValue());
  }

  List<Map.Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>(hm.entrySet());

  java.util.Collections.sort(entries, new FloatEntryComparator());

  hm = new LinkedHashMap<Float, Float>();
  for(Map.Entry e : entries)
    hm.put((Float)e.getKey(), (Float)e.getValue());

  println("5 LARGEST ENTRIES:");  
  int shownCount = 0;
  for (Map.Entry me : hm.entrySet()) {
    if(shownCount == 5)
      break;
    print("key is " + me.getKey());
    println(" value is " + me.getValue());
    ++shownCount;
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
class FloatEntryComparator implements Comparator<Map.Entry> { ... }
```

~ here we declare so-called comparator, a class used for sorting a list in a specific order.

```
void setup() { ... }
```

~ if I understand it right, this is one of entry points for Processing script. Since we are not drawing anything, we don't implement draw function (yet), only setup.

```
Map<Float,Float> hm = new HashMap<Float,Float>();
for(...) ...
```

~ this is initialization part, same as in your code.

```
List<Map.Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Map.Entry>(hm.entrySet());
```

~ here hashmap is converted to a list of entries

```
java.util.Collections.sort(entries, new FloatEntryComparator());
```

~ here list of entries is sorted by values in descending order

```
hm = new LinkedHashMap<Float, Float>();
for(Map.Entry e : entries)
  hm.put((Float)e.getKey(), (Float)e.getValue());
```

~ here list of entries is converted to hashmap. The resulting hashmap is sorted by values in descending order.

Here is the complete Processing script, tested against Processing 2.1:

https://gist.github.com/akhikhl/8258430

Comment: This is somewhat confusing but it looks useful! This groovy script wont run in Processing though right now. Ive never used it but it looks similar to Processing. Will I need to adjust it somehow to get it to run?

Comment: 1) what is Processing? 2) what did you try to make script running and how it did not work? 3) do you know how to start groovyConsole and run scripts with it?

Comment: The original code I posted is in Processing http://processing.org/. I've never used/heard of groovy script. I am working using the Processing IDE

Comment: ok, groovy is not a requirement. what i posted is pure java code. just copy/paste it to your java program, it should work right away. what exactly is confusing?

Comment: its a bunch of syntax errors. Processing syntax is not the same as java

Comment: line 3-7 is giving errors. 19 and 38 not processing syntax. Line 32 is incorrect as well. I dont know enough about what these functions to correct the syntax myself. I corrected/translated as much as I could but it still wont run.

Comment: Please, have a look - I completely rewritten my answer. Now the code does exactly what you want, in Processing IDE.

Comment: Thats Great! It runs. I'm going over it now to make sure I understand everything.

Answer (score 2):

If it is possible, replace `HashMap` by an implementation of [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), such as `TreeMap`. The iteration order of a `HashMap` is undefined.

With a `NavigableMap` you can sort it from higher to lower values by means of;

```
for (Map.Entry me : tm.descendingMap().entrySet() ()) {
  System.out.print("key is " + me.getKey());
  System.out.println(" value is " + me.getValue());
}
```

It is worth noting that [`descendingMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#descendingMap%28%29) does not actually sort the contents of the map (because the `TreeMap` is already sorted), but just return a *reverse view* of the original map.

Comment: So you are saying what I am trying to do is not possible with Hashmap and I need to use TreeMap instead?

Comment: Rigth. `HashMap` does not know about ordering between keys (indeed, keys are not required to be comparable). If you already have an instance of `HashMap`, you may construct a `TreeMap` from another map with `new TreeMap(hm)`, but that would require sorting all the key set, which is overkill if you only want the five higher values.

Note however that sorting a treemap is O(n.log(n)), while finding the 5 highest values by iterating is O(n).

Comment: I see. I need to see if I can use this in Processing

Comment: Do you call the TreeMap the same way as hasMap? also, how do you feed data into it? I cant find any documentation for it in Processing